# Showing a Hilbert Space has a Schauder Basis

Tags: real-analysis

Given $e^2$ = {<$x_1$, $x_2$, ...>, $x_i$ exists in the reals numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}$ $x_i$$^2$  < $\infty$. Show that the vectors $e_i$ \, i=1, ... defined by:

$e_1$ = <1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...>

$e_2$ = <0, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...>

$e_3$ = <0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...>

form a Schauder basis for $e^2$

How would you approach this question to be able to show that the set of vectors does form a Schauder Basis?

Comment: Presumably you have some definition of a Schauder basis.  Which parts of this definition are you having trouble showing?

Comment: Yes, there is a definition of the Schauder basis. It is The metric p(<$x_1$, $x_2$, ...>, (<$y_1$, $y_2$, ...>,) = √($\sum\limits_{i=1}^∞$ ($x_i$-$y_i$)$^2$ )< ∞

Comment: And, I was overall just a bit stuck on beginning the process to how to show this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider any $x = (x_1,x_2,\dots) \in \ell^2$.

Define the sequence of partial sums
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k e_k
$$
Show that $S_n$ converges to $x$ in $\ell^2$, so that
$$
x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k e_k
$$
Since $x \in \ell^2$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\{e_k\}$ forms a Schauder basis.